# When I press submit button, how can I store the value in a html <textarea> in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my attempt:

I want to be able to store the values entered in the text area's to submit data to a database or perform other tasks with the data. I have searched on Stack Overflow and there are many questions that are close to what I am asking for, but none that have been answered properly that I can see. I'm sure a seasoned developer will be able to provide quite a simple solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><textarea id="name">Any old text</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><textarea id="email"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm Email</td>
    <td><textarea id="confirmEmail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").onclick(function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var s = name.value;
        console.log(s);
    });



});


</script>
```

Comment: what's exactly the problem with the above code? Could you improve your question with this information?

Comment: You have to use `.on('click')` or `.click()` instead `onclick()`

Comment: You need to use a server-side code to save the data to db.

Comment: @Blue42 could you explain what exactly the problem you want whole textarea dynamic input to store in db or you want only name textarea dynamic value to store in db whats your need?

Comment: Ok thats odd. Not sure what the problem is then. Thanks for your help

Comment: `$("#button").on("click",function(){
    var name = $(*#name").val(); ...`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be helpfull

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            alert(name);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `click` instead of `onclick` because `onclick` is not a recognized jquery function

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var s = name.value;
        console.log(s);
    });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/My7q3/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out your problem

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NLHYF/1/)

you are using onclick

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var s = name.value;
        console.log(s);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use jQuery like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    alert($("#name").val());
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LuND/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess jquery may help  you ,

```
      $("#button").click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var s = name.value;
        console.log(s);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **.onclick** ,you may use **.click**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(name );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a form tag!
Then you should define the button as submit button and prevent it's default behavior, if the user has javascript enabled.

HTML

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><textarea id="name">Any old text</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><textarea id="email"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Email</td>
            <td><textarea id="confirmEmail"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
    </table>
</form>

<p>
    Value is <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#button").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        value = $('#name').val();
        $('#result').text( value );
    });
```

Check my working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RVG3p/1/.

Comment: Form tags are not mandatory. If he has no plans of submitting, there is no need for the form tags. The error was the onclick. Also no need to preventdefault on a plain button

Comment: HTML should always work without JavaScript. So if he plans to POST this via jQuery, he should always think about a non-ajax alternative, because it would not be accessable for people without javascript.

And if you use a form tag, you have to prevent it's default behavior!